# Converting from MS-SQL Server query to MySQL and DATEDIFF()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, dml

I have been convering the following MS-SQL Server's query to MySQL and I am stuck at this date part. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**Original MS-SQL Query (Working)**

```
select  top 4
    [Mon]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Monday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Tue]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Tuesday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Wed]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Wednesday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Thu]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Thursday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Fri]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Friday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Sat]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Saturday' then namount else 0 end),
    [Sun]=sum(case when datename(weekday, vrdate) = 'Sunday' then namount else 0 end)
from    stockmain
where    etype = 'sale' and  DATEDIFF(MONTH, vrdate, getDate()) = 0
group by datepart(week, vrdate)
order by datepart(week, vrdate) ;
```

**Respective MySQL Query (Not Working)**

Below is the respective MySQL Query and I am stuck at the `DATEDIFF` in `WHERE` clause.

```
select 
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Monday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Mon',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Tuesday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Tue',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Wednesday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Wed',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Thursday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Thu',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Friday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Fri',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Saturday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Sat',
        sum(case when date_format(vrdate, '%W') = 'Sunday' then namount else 0 end) as 'Sun'
from    stockmain
where    etype = 'sale' and DATEDIFF(MONTH, vrdate, CURDATE()) = 0
group by WEEK(VRDATE)
order by WEEK(VRDATE) desc
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL equivalent of how `datediff` works on SQL Server is [`timestampdiff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, vrdate, curdate()) = 0
```

The following may be equivalent, depending on how `datediff` rounds the month before its calculation:

```
WHERE MONTH(vrdate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: I was just pondering whether it is actually equivalent - I think it's not but I don't have the software at hand right now to test. `timestampdiff` should work fine though.

Comment: Both produced the same result. I'm going with the second one.